# SSH Tunnel with Port Forwarding

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm attempting to establish a SSH tunnel to an AWS EC2 instance using:
`ssh -i ~/aws_rsa.pem -ND 8157 hadoop@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com`

From the debug log below, it appears the session stalls after authentication. Does anyone have any suggestions on possible resolutions?

```
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:8157 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 8157.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8157.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

Comment: Show us the command you're using to attempt to connect.

Comment: @Safado, I edited question to include executed command.

Comment: Is this cluster using Kerberos?

Comment: Is that the master node? Also is this EMR?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-ssh-tunnel.html